# Regex to match SSH url parts

Tags: regex, url, ssh, matching

Given the following SSH urls:

```
git@github.com:james/example
git@github.com:007/example
git@github.com:22/james/example
git@github.com:22/007/example
```

How can I pull the following:

```
{user}@{host}:{optional port}{path (user/repo)}
```

As you can see in the example, one of the usernames is numeric and NOT a port. I can't figure out how to workaround that. A port isn't always in the URL too.

My current regex is:

```
^(?P<user>[^@]+)@(?P<host>[^:\s]+)?:(?:(?P<port>\d{1,5})\/)?(?P<path>[^\\].*)$
```

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: A small parser maybe?

Comment: @Jan do you mean not using regex to do this?

Comment: See my answer bewlo (but go with the other, shorter one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy quantifiers to the rescue!

This seems to work well and satisfies the optional port:

```
^
(?P<user>.*?)@
(?P<host>.*?):
(?:(?P<port>.*?)/)?
(?P<path>.*?/.*?)
$
```

The line breaks are not part of the regex because the `/x` modifier is enabled. Remove all line breaks if you are not using `/x`.

https://regex101.com/r/wdE30O/5

---

Thank you [@Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231450/jan) for the [optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698369/regex-to-match-ssh-url-parts/57698506?noredirect=1#comment101851867_57698506).

Comment: @ThatGuy343 correct, `007` comes after the colon `:`

Comment: @ThatGuy343 if `007` is not the port then which capture group should contain it? Should that entry be ignored altogether since it is "invalid"? My goal was to create a simple parser, not a validator

Comment: 007 is a username, and part of the path. the path group is like this: `username/repo`

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Now I am even more confused. Please edit your question and mark the expected user, host, port, and path captures from each example you've listed.

Comment: @ThatGuy343 so the colon is always guaranteed?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus +1 I think you are close, but what if git@github.com:22/james ... It will match path as 22/james, when should just be james I believe...

Comment: @vs97 my intent was to build a dumb parser, not validator. OP's question is still hazy at best until they can expand upon it per my request. Also, your example doesn't seem to fit any of theirs

Comment: Really great work man, thank you for this. The trailing slash is included in the match but this small tweaked version fixes that: `^(?P<user>.*?)@(?P<host>.*?):(?:(?:(?P<port>.*?)\/)?(?P<path>.*?\/.*?))$`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: +1 but a few optimizations: a) use verbose mode, b) the non-capturing as you're using it now is superfluous and c) get rid of the forward slash for the port. All in all see https://regex101.com/r/wdE30O/5

Comment: @Jan Hmm, never thought to make use of `/x` but it really makes a huge legibility difference. I think that trying to do it all in one line contributed to me having the slash in the port ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Check out the update. Jan made some great suggestions.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: You're welcome. Indeed, the verbose flag makes the expressions more readable and helps me a lot when debugging code.

Comment: @ThatGuy343, Your tweaked version didn't quite work for me, as it parses a URI of `v3/ORGANIZATION/PROJECT/REPO` with `v3` as the port when it should be part of the path. Tweaking it from any character to and digit worked for me: `^(?P<user>.*?)@(?P<host>.*?):(?:(?:(?P<port>\d*?)\/)?(?P<path>.*?\/.*?))$`

Answer (score 2):

If you're on `Python`, you could write your very own parser:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

data = """git@github.com:james/example
git@github.com:007/example
git@github.com:22/james/example
git@github.com:22/007/example"""

class GitVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    grammar = Grammar(
        r"""
        expr        = user at domain colon rest

        user        = word+
        domain      = ~"[^:]+"
        rest        = (port path) / path

        path        = word slash word
        port        = digits slash

        slash       = "/"
        colon       = ":"
        at          = "@"
        digits      = ~"\d+"
        word        = ~"\w+"

        """)

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_user(self, node, visited_children):
        return {"user": node.text}

    def visit_domain(self, node, visited_children):
        return {"domain": node.text}

    def visit_rest(self, node, visited_children):
        child = visited_children[0]
        if isinstance(child, list):
            # first branch, port and path
            return {"port": child[0], "path": child[1]}
        else:
            return {"path": child}

    def visit_path(self, node, visited_children):
        return node.text

    def visit_port(self, node, visited_children):
        digits, _ = visited_children
        return digits.text

    def visit_expr(self, node, visited_children):
        out = {}
        _ = [out.update(child) for child in visited_children if isinstance(child, dict)]
        return out

gv = GitVisitor()
for line in data.split("\n"):
    result = gv.parse(line)
    print(result)
```

Which would yield

```
{'user': 'git', 'domain': 'github.com', 'path': 'james/example'}
{'user': 'git', 'domain': 'github.com', 'path': '007/example'}
{'user': 'git', 'domain': 'github.com', 'port': '22', 'path': 'james/example'}
{'user': 'git', 'domain': 'github.com', 'port': '22', 'path': '007/example'}
```

A parser allows for some ambiguity which you obviously have here.

Comment: You know, I started participating in the regex tag a little over 2 months ago to improve my skills and I feel like I've made good progress; not sure if I am an expert but at least regex doesn't seem overwhelmingly cryptic anymore (I owe most of this to using regex visualizers). Never did I think that I would get into parsers but your post is so nonchalantly "meh, try this parser" that this might be my next adventure, lol

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Glad to have another traveler here. A good starting point is https://tomassetti.me/guide-parsing-algorithms-terminology/ for a general overview and https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious for a PEG parser in `Python`. It really widens the possibilities.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Shameless self-advertisement: you could very well combine both regular expressions and a parser to have the best of both worlds, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57749422/1231450

Answer (score 0):

Here's another regex that handles IP addresses:

```
^
((?P<user>.*?)@)?
(?P<host>.*?)
(:(?P<port>.*?))?
(/(?P<path>.*))?
$
```

Test vectors:

```
104.171.200.112
104.171.200.112:22
ubuntu@104.171.200.112
ubuntu@104.171.200.112:22
ubuntu@104.171.200.112:22/test
104.171.200.112:22/test
104.171.200.112/test/
git@github.com:james/example
git@github.com:007/example
git@github.com:22/james/example
git@github.com:22/007/example
```

https://regex101.com/r/G0Arqw/1