# selecting variations of phone numbers using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
    import re
    s = 'so the 1234 2-1-1919 215.777.9839 1333331234 20-20-2000 A1234567 (515)2331129 7654321B (511)231-1134 512-333-1134 7777777 a7727373 there 1-22-2001 *1831 5647 and !2783 '
    reg = r'[()\d-]{7,}'
    r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
```

I have the following `reg` that gives the following

```
    r1
['2-1-1919',
 '1333331234',
 '20-20-2000',
 '1234567',
 '(515)2331129',
 '7654321',
 '(511)231-1134',
 '512-333-1134',
 '7777777',
 '7727373',
 '1-22-2001']
```

I want to get the following output

```
['(515)2331129', 
    '(511)231-1134',
 '512-333-1134']
```

So I tried to alter `reg = r'[()\d-]{7,}'` by adding `\b`

```
reg = r'[\b()\b\d-]{7,}'
```

But this doesnt work. How do I change  `reg = r'[()\d-]{7,}'` to get the output I want?

Comment: `[()\d-]` is a character class that matches `(`, `)`, `-` or a digit `\b` in a character class means backspace.

Comment: @Toto - `Reference - What does this regex mean?` is too broad a topic, he's asking how to match variations of phone numbers.

Comment: @sln: They will find there what is a character class and the meaning of their regex.

Comment: @Toto - I don't think a fopa in remedial class understanding warrants a redirection to an over bloated regex link page trying to replace the google search engine. Then %99 of the regex questions qualify for that. Who decides that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, we could use alternation based on the cases you might have:

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\d{7}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}
```

We can also include additional boundaries if it'd be necessary:

```
(?<!\S)(?:\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\d{7}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4})(?!\S)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lNYb3R/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\d{7}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}"

string = """
so the 1234 2-1-1919 215.777.9839 1333331234 20-20-2000 A1234567 (515)2331129 7654321B (511)231-1134 512-333-1134 7777777 a7727373 there 1-22-2001 *1831 5647 and !2783 (511) 231-1134 ( 511)231-1134 (511 ) 231-1134
511-2311134

"""


print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['(515)2331129', '(511)231-1134', '512-333-1134', '(511) 231-1134', '( 511)231-1134', '(511 ) 231-1134']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/akbwAR/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/akbwAR/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To put my two cents in, you could use a regex/parser combination as in:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.expressions import IncompleteParseError, ParseError
import re

junk = """so the 1234 2-1-1919 215.777.9839 1333331234 20-20-2000 A1234567 (515)2331129 7654321B 
(511)231-1134 512-333-1134 7777777 a7727373 there 1-22-2001 *1831 5647 and !2783"""

rx = re.compile(r'[-()\d]+')
grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    phone       = area part part
    area        = (lpar digits rpar) / digits
    part        = dash? digits

    lpar        = "("
    rpar        = ")"
    dash        = "-"
    digits      = ~"\d{3,4}"
    """
)

for match in rx.finditer(junk):
    possible_number = match.group(0)
    try:
        tree = grammar.parse(possible_number)
        print(possible_number)
    except (ParseError, IncompleteParseError):
        pass
```

This yields

```
(515)2331129
(511)231-1134
512-333-1134
```

The idea here is to first match possible candidates which are then checked with the parser grammar.