# modification of selecting variations of phone numbers using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
import re
s =  'nums here (111)123-4567 or (1-800-111-2222)(123)1234567 or 321-123-4567 or ( 112)123-4567 or (113 )123-4567'
```

My goal is to get all phone numbers from `s`.

From [selecting variations of phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748369/selecting-variations-of-phone-numbers-using-regex) I try the following:

```
reg = r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\d{7}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}' 
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
r1
```

Which gives me close to what I want

```
['(111)123-4567',
 '800-111-2222',
 '(123)1234567',
 '321-123-4567',
 '( 112)123-4567',
 '(113 )123-4567']
```

However, I would like `(1-800-111-2222)` instead of the partial `800-111-2222`

My desired output is the following

```
 ['(111)123-4567',
     '(1-800-111-2222)',
     '(123)1234567',
     '321-123-4567',
     '( 112)123-4567',
     '(113 )123-4567']
```

How do I alter

`reg = r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\d{7}|\(\s*\d{3}\s*\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}'`

to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
s =  'nums here (111)123-4567 or (1-800-111-2222)(123)1234567 or 321-123-4567 or ( 112)123-4567 or (113 )123-4567'

reg="\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}|\(\d{1}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\)|\(\d{3}\)\d{7}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\(\s+\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}|\(\d{3}\s+\)\d{3}-\d{4}"

r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
r1
```

Running above, outputs:

```
['(111)123-4567',
 '(1-800-111-2222)',
 '(123)1234567',
 '321-123-4567',
 '( 112)123-4567',
 '(113 )123-4567']
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
\(?\s*\d?\s*-?\d{3}\s*[)-]?\s*\d{3}\s*-?\s*\d{4}\)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/tc9E1E/1