# getting phone numbers with periods using regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
s = ' 1.210.223.1112 (113)-945-6373; 222.212.2333 (111)123-4567 (111)1234567 (111 )123-4567 \n(1-100-533-1710)the  ( 111)123-4567 Z1902022 (111)123-4567 N18-2181 Z1234567 1-22-2001 (100) 115-5198 f: (110)-111-1111 112.222.1112 (222)-222-3337 (120) 305-1314'
```

I have a list of phone numbers and I would like to get all variations present in the string `s`. From [modification of selecting variations of phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067089/modification-of-selecting-variations-of-phone-numbers-using-regex) I have tried the following

```
reg = r'\(?\s*\d?\s*-?\d{3}\s*[)-]?-?\s*\d{3}\s*-?\s*\d{4}\)?'
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
r1
```

Which gives me close to what I want

```
['(113)-945-6373',
 '(111)123-4567',
 '(111)1234567',
 '(111 )123-4567',
 '(1-100-533-1710)',
 '( 111)123-4567',
 '(111)123-4567',
 '(100) 115-5198',
 '(110)-111-1111',
 '(222)-222-3337',
 '(120) 305-1314']
```

However, it is missing `1.210.223.1112` and `222.212.2333`.

I have tried modifying `reg` by adding a `.` but this doesn't give me what I am looking for

```
reg = r'\(?\s.*\d?\s*-?\d{3}\s*[)-]?-?\s*\d{3}\s*-?\s*\d{4}\)?'
```

My desired output is as follow which includes `1.210.223.1112` and `222.212.2333`

```
['1.210.223.1112',
 '(113)-945-6373',
  '222.212.2333',
 '(111)123-4567',
 '(111)1234567',
 '(111 )123-4567',
 '(1-100-533-1710)',
 '( 111)123-4567',
 '(111)123-4567',
 '(100) 115-5198',
 '(110)-111-1111',
 '(222)-222-3337',
 '(120) 305-1314']
```

How do I alter `reg` to get my desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'(?:\b\d[.-])?\(?\s?\d{3}[.) -]{0,2}\d{3}[ .-]?\d{4}',s)
Out[31]: 
['1.210.223.1112',
 '(113)-945-6373',
 ' 222.212.2333',
 '(111)123-4567',
 '(111)1234567',
 '(111 )123-4567',
 '1-100-533-1710',
 '( 111)123-4567',
 '(111)123-4567',
 '(100) 115-5198',
 '(110)-111-1111',
 ' 112.222.1112',
 '(222)-222-3337',
 '(120) 305-1314']
```

Comment: @EER Be aware that this answer matches whitespace in front of the number with dots, e.g. ' 222.212.2333' and ' 112.222.1112'.

Answer (score 4):

You were close, just add an optional dot match `\.?` when you're looking for `-` , as well as separate the case when you have `( whitespace` and a whitespace in front of number:

```
(?:(?:\(\s)|\(?\d?)-?\.?\d{3}\s*[)-]?-?\.?\s*\d{3}\s*-?\.?\s*\d{4}\)?
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ejOOWq/4)

Equivalent, but using OR `|` and non-matching groups :

```
(?:(?:\(\s)|\(?\d?)(?:-|\.)?\d{3}\s*[)-]?(?:-|\.)?\s*\d{3}\s*(?:-|\.)?\s*\d{4}\)?
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ejOOWq/5)

**Output:**

```
['1.210.223.1112',
 '(113)-945-6373',
 '222.212.2333',
 '(111)123-4567',
 '(111)1234567',
 '(111 )123-4567',
 '1-100-533-1710',
 '( 111)123-4567',
 '(111)123-4567',
 '(100) 115-5198',
 '(110)-111-1111',
 '112.222.1112',
 '(222)-222-3337',
 '(120) 305-1314']
```