# Regex to detect Date of birth

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex which detects the date of birth in the given paragraph text.

```
import re

dob = re.compile(r'(?:\bbirth\b|\bbirth(?:day|date)).{0,20}\n? \b((?:(?<!\:)(?<!\:\d)[0-3]?\d(?:st|nd|rd|th)?\s+(?:of\s+)?(?:jan\.?|january|feb\.?|february|mar\.?|march|apr\.?|april|may|jun\.?|june|jul\.?|july|aug\.?|august|sep\.?|september|oct\.?|october|nov\.?|november|dec\.?|december)|(?:jan\.?|january|feb\.?|february|mar\.?|march|apr\.?|april|may|jun\.?|june|jul\.?|july|aug\.?|august|sep\.?|september|oct\.?|october|nov\.?|november|dec\.?|december)\s+(?<!\:)(?<!\:\d)[0-3]?\d(?:st|nd|rd|th)?)(?:\,)?\s*(?:\d{4})?|\b[0-3]?\d[-\./][0-3]?\d[-\./]\d{2,4})\b',re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

data = " Hi This is Goku and my birthday is on 6th Aug but to be clear it is on 1994-08-06."

l = dob.findall(data)

print(l)
```

> o/p: ['6th Aug ']

I just want to add one more feature like if something in this format YYYY-MM-DD is present in the text, then that should also be  the date of birth.

*(where YYYY --> 19XX-20XX , MM --> 01-12 , DD --> 01-31)*

For Ex:

```
data = " Hi This is Goku and my birthday is on 6th Aug but to be clear it is on 1994-08-06."
```

Then the output should be

> output: ['6th Aug ', '1994-08-06']

**where can i add the part in the regex so it would detect this YYYY-MM-DD format also.??**

Comment: So basically a regex that detect any dates in a string?

Comment: Not exactly, I need the output as i mentioned above.

Comment: What about this string: `Hi my name is August von Spiff the third, but people call me Aug 3rd. I'm gonna celebrate my birthday on May 4th (2019-05-04), but the actual day is on the 7th of may` ?

Comment: 2019-05-04 this should be detected. And the output should be ['May 4th', '2019-05-04']

Comment: @JinKazama but August von Spiff's birthday is May 7th so why do you want to extract the wrong data?

Comment: Its not about extracting the wrong data or right data ( I am not performing any machine learning over here ;)...  )....      May 7th won't be extracted because i consider text part of 20 charecters before the date. ( see this in regex .{0,20} )

Comment: Honestly, you have created a very complex regex. May I ask why is it that you cannot figure out how to add the simple `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I tried in all possible ways but I was not able to get the results( with YYYY-MM-DD format also) . Thats why i raised a qstn in stackoverflow waiting for some experts to answer. And i dont think that the regex is complex if someone's good in regex :)

Comment: If you wrote that from scratch then I would say that you're at least a "little" good at regex. If you haven't stumbled upon regex visualizers yet then I would like to introduce you to https://regex101.com/ and on the left side you can select Python as your regex flavor.

Comment: At regex101 you should enable the `/x` modifier so that you can break out your regex across multiple lines without telling the engine to search for new lines. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57698506/2191572 for an example of how much better `/x` makes things in terms of readability.

Answer (score 0):

this will detect YYYY-MM-DD

```
re.search('([0-9]+-)+[0-9]+',data).group()
```

output:

```
'1994-08-06'
```

Comment: I just need some modifications in my regex that would give the output as i showed in the question. Your code is not useful here. Please read my question clearly.